# Queues in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, queue, beanstalkd

I am working in a project developed on Laravel 4.2. 
I am not able to get the idea about queuing service of laravel. I have read many documents about it but still things are not clear.

Should I compare Queue and cron job ?
when we put a cron job on server, We mention a time when the cron will run. But in the case of queue I could not find the place where time of run is mentioned.
There are some files in App/command directory and code is running on my server but I am helpless to find the time of run OR how to stop these queues.

Please guide me about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queue is a service where you add the tasks for later.

Generally you ask other service provider like iron.io to call your application to have the task processes asynchronously and repeat the call if it fails the first time. This allows you to respond to the application user quickly and leave the task to be processed in the background.

If you use local sync driver then task will be done immediately during the same request.

Comment: Thanks for response. but how can I know about the time when this queue services are being called. I have a database table and I had updated records using my external script. All records were fine and when I checked records today all were again updated by the code present in command file. To stop it I have commented the code . But I wanna know , where is time mentioned to run this queue file. or how can I remove this queue.